# Apache2 - How to disable directory listing on a Virtual Host?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, apache2.4, web-admin

I'm running an Apache2.4 webserver on Ubuntu 18.04, and I'd like to disable directory listing on one of the virtual hosts.

I realize that I can do this with a .htaccess file, but I'd much prefer to do so in the virtual host config. I edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/008-vhost.conf` and now it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>

ServerName example.com
Include /etc/ssl-provider/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl-provider/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl-provider/example.com/privkey.pem


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
                ServerAlias www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory />
            Options -Indexes
        </Directory>

        Redirect permanent "/" https://example.com\/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I would have expected `Options -Indexes` to do the trick here. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you make sure, that `/etc/apache2/sites-available/008-vhost.conf` is actually symlinked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Comment: Yeah. The host is enabled, and other settings go through. I'm just surprised that ``Options -Indexes`` doesn't. Everything else is pretty much the default Ubuntu 18.04 install of Apache2.4, so there must be _some_ overriding config, I just can't find where.

Comment: mod_info would tell you where things are if `grep` isn't getting it done.

Comment: Huh? What would you have me doing in mod_info?

Comment: if you use Ubuntu or similar there is actually the following in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf `<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`
This overrules what you specified in your Directory context. Maybe just try to put `Options -Indexes` in the Vhost context instead of Directory.

Comment: Perfect!! You found it. Any way I can fix my vhosts so that I can make directory-specific configurations this won't override? (Figure Ubuntu will keep overwriting that apache2.conf every time I update, so I don't want to fix it there.)